# Can you explain us a simple example, for a mathematical function, of Kramers–Kronig relations?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, complex-integration, analytic-functions, cauchy-principal-value

I am interesting in learn easy facts about new issues of complex analysis. I've read in **Wikipedia** the statement of [Kramers–Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations).

> **Question.** Please can you provide us **a simple example for mathematicians** of such theorem? I am asking thus about a $\chi_1(\omega)$ being the real part, and $\chi_2(\omega)$ the imaginary part respectively, of a complex function $\chi(\omega)$ satyisfying the hypothesis of the theorem, and how one gets from  such example one of those integrals. Since I can read the identities from Wikipedia, only are required the calculations for a simple example inspired in a mathematical function. **Thanks in advance.**

In the article of [spanish Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaciones_de_Kramers-Kronig) there are *different* expressions for such identities (you can use these or previous).

In the english version of Wikipedia are referenced the genuine works due to **Kramers** and **Kroning**.

Comment: http://residuetheorem.com/2015/08/07/cauchy-principal-value/

Comment: Many thanks for the reference @RonGordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kramers Kronig relations are used in general to find the realtion between the real and imaginary parts of any complex numbers, e.g. if you know the real part then you can derive the imaginary part and vice versa. but there are some constraints to in these relations to be appicable for any complex function, so not all of the complex functions are KK transformable. 
you can take a look at this link, i think it is helpfull
http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss2/linearresponse/causality.php

also this 
http://www.iam.kit.edu/wet/plainhtml/Download/Derivation_Kramers-Kronig.pdf

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and these nice references. Tomorrow I try read and understand it. I consider that with these and Gordon's example is the best solution and reference, thus I accept it as an aswer.